# How to recognise and extract alpha numeric characters

Tags: r, regex, alphanumeric

I want to extract alphanumeric characters from a partiular sentence in R.
I have tried the following:

```
aa=grep("[:alnum:]","abc")
```

.This should return `integer(0)`,but it returns 1,which should not be the case as `"abc"` is not an alphanumeric.
What am I missing here?
Essentially I am looking for a function,that only searches for characters that are combinations of both alphabets and numbers,example:"ABC-0112","PCS12SCH" 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It returns 1 because there is at least 1 alphanumeric character in "abc". And `grep("[[:alnum:]]", c("ABC-0112","PCS12SCH"))` works for both the other strings.  Not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[:alnum:]]` matches alphabets or digits. To match the string which contains the both then you should use,

```
x <- c("ABC", "ABc12", "--A-1", "abc--", "89=A")
grep("(.*[[:alpha:]].*[[:digit:]]|.*[[:digit:]].*[[:alpha:]])", x)
# [1] 2 3 5
```

or

```
which(grepl("[[:alpha:]]", x) & grepl("[[:digit:]]", x))
# [1] 2 3 5
```