# How to grep a string that only has alphanumerics in r?

Tags: r, regex

for example, I want only the first two entries:

```
sttt=c("flyingFish1", "toadie23","h!toyou!")
k=grep("[[:alnum:]]", sttt, value = TRUE )
k
```

but this gives me all three entries.

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712380/how-to-recognise-and-extract-alpha-numeric-characters-in-r

Answer (score 3):

Each of those strings does match `[[:alnum:]]` - that is, they all have at least one alphanumeric character! If you'd like to match against the entire string, try:

```
sttt=c("flyingFish1", "toadie23","h!toyou!")
k=grep("^[[:alnum:]]+$", sttt, value = TRUE )
k
```

I've added three characters to your regular expression:

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `$` matches the end of the string
- `+` allows the `[[:alnum:]]` class to be repeated one or more times.

Your original regex matched strings that contain an `alnum`. This regex matches strings that are made up entirely of `alnum`s.

Comment: Also `grep("[^[:alnum:]]", sttt, value = TRUE, invert=TRUE)` or `sttt[!grepl("[^[:alnum:]]", sttt)]`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to *omit any character vectors having a non-alphanumeric char*.

Use

```
sttt=c("flyingFish1", "toadie23","h!toyou!")
k=grep("[^[:alnum:]]", sttt, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)
k
# => [1] "flyingFish1" "toadie23"
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/6lzfeu).

The `[^[:alnum:]]` is a *negated bracket expression* that will match any char but an `alnum` (alphanumeric) char. Since you need to get the items that are not matched with the pattern, use `invert=TRUE` that will fetch the right items.